# Java - bson filter for mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a filter in my java backend. My document looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("abcdefg"),
"active" : false,
"externalId" : "332",
"link" : "mylink",
"owner" : {
    "sourceValue" : {
        "externalId" : "0000",
        "familyName" : "jobs",
        "givenName" : "ben",
        "username" : "bjobs"
    }
},
"title" : "title",
"tool" : "app",
"hidden" : false,
"accessable" : false
}
```

With this code, I'm able to get all documents for one `owner`:

```
  private Bson ownerFilter(String username) {
return orNonNull(
    andNonNull(
        exists("owner.overrideValue", false), eq("owner.sourceValue.username", ntAccount)),
    eq("owner.overrideValue.username", username));
}
```

which is good! What do I have to add now that I get only these documents, where `"active" : true`?

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you use jpa query method `findByActive(Boolean active)`?

Comment: how can I use that?

Comment: Refer https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb#1-findbyx